# Magento version 1.7.0.2 security patches update

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, security, patches

I am using Magento  version 1.7.0.2 .I have not upgraded it newer version.There are several security patches update notification in my admin notification panel.

Which security patches do I need to update for my Magento version? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are  also listing of patches for version 1.9.2.1 and 1.9.2.3 . How do I apply these patches?Is it necessary to update?Do I need to upgrade my Magento version?

Comment: Up to now, all patches were released for 1.7.0.2 as well, so you don't need to update Magento. The patches exist in different versions, choose the one that matches your Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

```
After Magento 1.7.02 below patches are released you can check below 
SUPEE-5344, 
SUPEE-5994, 
SUPEE-6285,
SUPEE-6237, 
SUPEE-6482,
SUPEE-6788, 
SUPEE-7616, 
SUPEE-7405

Please take your site backup before apply the patch and you can download the all patch files from below URL 
https://magentary.com/
```

Comment: please see my comment above.

Comment: I strongly advise against downloading patch files from untrusted 3rd party URLs. All patches are available at https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Every patch have magento version files so you don't need to update the 1.9 patch files you need to only update the 1.7.0.2 version patch files. I have listed patch list above so you can download patch files according to magneto version.